# Python Regex Replaces All Matches

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a string such as "Hey people #Greetings how are we? #Awesome" and every time there is a hashtag I need to replace the word with another string.

I have the following code which works when only one hashtag but the problem is that because it uses the sub to replace all instances, it overwrites the every string with the last string.

```
match = re.findall(tagRE, content)
print(match)
for matches in match:
    print(matches)
    newCode = "The result is: " + matches + " is it correct?"
    match = re.sub(tagRE, newCode, content)
```

What should I be doing instead to replace just the current match? Is there a way of using re.finditer to replace the current match or another way?

Comment: You can supply a function to `re.sub` to do this https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter's method would work. You could also just supply the match object as the regex string so that it only replaces that specific match. Like so:

```
newCode = "whatever" + matches + "whatever"
content = re.sub(matches, newCode, content)
```

I ran some sample code and this was the output.

```
import re

content = "This is a #wonderful experiment. It's #awesome!"
matches = re.findall('#\w+', content)
print(matches)
for match in matches:
    newCode = match[1:]
    print(content)
    content = re.sub(match, newCode, content)
    print(content)

#['#wonderful', '#awesome']
#This is a #wonderful experiment. It's #awesome!
#This is a wonderful experiment. It's #awesome!
#This is a wonderful experiment. It's #awesome!
#This is a wonderful experiment. It's awesome!
```

Comment: Surprised I did not consider this myself, exactly what I was after thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "Hey people #Greetings how are we? #Awesome"
In [3]: re.sub(r'(?:^|\s)(\#\w+)', ' replace_with_new_string', s)
Out[3]: 'Hey people replace_with_new_string how are we? replace_with_new_string'
```

Comment: Thanks although the issue is reusing the match in the replacement so that each text is different.